# Select the row_number or fake identity

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that did not have an identity column added to it.  I don't really need one for any specific purpose.

I had 821 rows and I did a test of 500 more.  Now I need to check those 500 files and I was looking for a simple way to

select * from table where row_number > 821

I've tried row_number() but I can't have them be ordered, I need all rows above 821 returned.

Comment: If you can't have them ordered then the number 821 has no meaning.  I could put the 500 items you want in rows 1-500 and then your query would not be helpful.  Why can't they be ordered?

Comment: They are ordered, the default order is the order in which they were inserted.  I don't want to change that order.

Comment: @JamesWilson *the default order* that's not a thing. Although it understandable because the data often comes back the same way. But you'll always be at the mercy of the Database Engine

Comment: So there is no column you can use to uniquely identify each row? If there were you could select all rows that are not in a select of the top 821. But why not just modify the table design to facilitate reliable access in the ways you need?

Comment: @ConradFrix Hrm, so the very first item I inserted will not always be the very first things returned?  Guess I'll have to add a column to the table for future testing.

Comment: @hatchet Sadly no, this was a storage table that would eventually be deleted.  Nothing unique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A table is an unordered bag of rows. You can't identify the first 820 rows that were inserted unless you have some column to identify the order of insertion (a trusted IDENTITY or datetime column, for example). Otherwise you are throwing a bunch of marbles on the floor and asking the first person who walks into the room to identify the first 820 marbles that fell.

Here is a very simple example that demonstrates that output order cannot be predicted, and certainly can't be relied upon to be FIFO (and also shows a case where HABO's "solution" breaks):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.foo(id INT, x CHAR(1));

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX x ON dbo.foo(x);

-- or CREATE INDEX x ON dbo.foo(x, id); -- doesn't require a clustered index to prove

INSERT dbo.foo VALUES(1,'z');
INSERT dbo.foo VALUES(2,'y');
INSERT dbo.foo VALUES(3,'x');
INSERT dbo.foo VALUES(4,'w');
INSERT dbo.foo VALUES(5,'v');
INSERT dbo.foo VALUES(6,'u');
INSERT dbo.foo VALUES(7,'t');
INSERT dbo.foo VALUES(8,'s');

SELECT TOP (5) id, x, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
 FROM dbo.foo;

SELECT * FROM dbo.foo;
```

Results:

```
---- ---- ----
8    s    1
7    t    2
6    u    3
5    v    4
4    w    5

---- ----
8    s
7    t
6    u
5    v
4    w
3    x
2    y
1    z
```

[SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2b637/1)

Comment: Thanks for helping me to understand that all better.  I'll have to remember to always add an identity or dateadded columns in the future.

Comment: What results do you get if the table has no clustered index (i.e. a heap table)? It sounds like that's the situation in the OP's case.

Comment: @hatchet (a) I'm not sure why you think the OP's case is a heap. Not having an identity column does not mean "not having a clustered index" and (b) if you see in the code sample it also reproduces the same problem with a heap having a covering non-clustered index. If you don't have something to order by, you can't rely on order. PERIOD. There is no magic here, it's simply undefined - SQL Server can return the data in whatever order is most efficient, and that will rarely be the order of insertion.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I made that assumption because he said nothing uniquely identified a row, and there was no order. It's possible there is a non-unique clustered index, but based on what he said, it sounded like there were no indexes of any kind since an index would imply some order. Also, order may be undefined, but physically there is always some inherent order to the underlying data, and based on the indexes (or lack thereof), that order may or may not be order of insertion. But I agree that counting on implicit order is not good.

Comment: @hatchet I think you're confusing logical and physical, and storage with retrieval. There are far too many variables to even imply that the physical order of the data is the way the order will be returned by any arbitrary query. Sure, that happens sometimes, but it is dumb luck.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a hack that may help, but is **NOT** a generally useful solution:

```
Row_Number() over (order by (select NULL)) as UntrustworthyRowNumber
```

Comment: This actually won't work unless (a) it is a heap (and even then I'd be concerned if the heap were clustered or there was a covering NC index) or (b) there is a clustered index that happens to coincide with the insert order. In other words, lots of disclaimers, and it still can't be trusted beyond statistics updates, service packs, version upgrades, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I said "heap were clustered" but I meant "heap were partitioned"